# AsyncTask: DoInBackground(String...) clashes with DoInBackground(Params...)?

Tags: android, string, android-asynctask

When trying to use `Async task` to carry out an HTTP post I get the following:

```
ASyncTask: DoInBackground(String...) clashes with DoInBackground(Params...) in Android.os.AsyncTask; attempting to use incompatible return type
```

How do I fix this? This is my first time using AsyncTask.

**Specific line causing error:**

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
```

**Code from the full AsyncTask:**

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
    {
        boolean success = false;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            StringBuilder respData = new StringBuilder();
            URL url = new URL("MY_URL");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) conn;

            httpUrlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "App");
            httpUrlConnection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            httpUrlConnection.setReadTimeout(30000);

            httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();
            //InputStream postStream = toInputStream(toSubmit, "UTF-8");
            InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(toSubmit.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            try {
                copy(stream, os);
            } finally {
                stream.close();
                os.flush();
                os.close();
            }

            httpUrlConnection.connect();

            int responseCode = httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (200 == responseCode) {
                InputStream is = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = null;
                try {
                    isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                    char[] buffer = new char[1024];
                    int len;
                    while ((len = isr.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        respData.append(buffer, 0, len);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (isr != null)
                    {
                        isr.close();
                        success = true;
                    }
                }
                is.close();
            }
            else {
                // use below to get error stream
                // inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getErrorStream();
            }
            return "done";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Declare you class like this

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

The last param is type you will return from doInBackground and its also input to onPostExecute.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it but I know get the error with postexecute: onPostExecute(java.lang.string) cannot be applied to (java.lang.void) ?

Comment: Change you onPostExecute to protected void onPostExecute(String result).

Answer (score 3):

From the documenation for `AsyncTask`:

> An asynchronous task is defined by 3 generic types, called Params,
>   Progress and Result

Your `doInBackground()` method returns a `String` value, but the `Result` parameter is `Void` in your code. Changing the `return` value of `doInBackground()` from `String` to `Void` will correct the problem - or, you can substitute `<String, Void, Void>` for `<String, Void, String>`

Comment: Thanks, that solved it but I know get the error with postexecute: onPostExecute(java.lang.string) cannot be applied to (java.lang.void) ?

Comment: @java12340000 Substitute `protected String doInBackground(String... params)` for `protected Void doInBackground(String... params)`, return `null` rather than `"done"` from `doInBackground()` and keep your class declaration as `private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>` - Seems the best solution in your case